# C++: modified a function, tried to recompile, got undefined reference to that function

Tags: c++, makefile

I modified the body of a function `foo` in a `.cpp` file that is part of a large piece of software ('large' such that lots of header and implementation files calling each other from various directories). The function still takes the same parameters and returns the same thing, so nothing to modify in the header file.

I read somewhere that one of the advantages of C++ is that it's smart enough to recompile only what needs to be.

So I (naively?) did `make all`, but then I got errors from source files which call that function; the errors all said `undefined reference to 'foo'`.

From the info above, is there something I have clearly done wrong?

---

Ok you asked for the code, here it is before:

```
bool ReadImageToDatum(const string& filename, const int label,
    const int height, const int width, Datum* datum) {
  cv::Mat cv_img;
  if (height > 0 && width > 0) {
    cv::Mat cv_img_origin = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::resize(cv_img_origin, cv_img, cv::Size(height, width));
  } else {
    cv_img = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  }
  if (!cv_img.data) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Could not open or find file " << filename;
    return false;
  }
  datum->set_channels(3);
  datum->set_height(cv_img.rows);
  datum->set_width(cv_img.cols);
  datum->set_label(label);
  datum->clear_data();
  datum->clear_float_data();
  string* datum_string = datum->mutable_data();
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    for (int h = 0; h < cv_img.rows; ++h) {
      for (int w = 0; w < cv_img.cols; ++w) {
        datum_string->push_back(
            static_cast<char>(cv_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(h, w)[c]));
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here it is after:

```
#include <unistd.h> 

bool ReadImageToDatum(string& filename, const int label,
    const int height, const int width, Datum* datum) {
  cv::Mat cv_img;
  /* dalyac addition to read/follow symlink if symlink*/
  char buf[200]; 
  if (readlink(filename.c_str(), buf, 200) > 0) {
    filename = std::string(buf);
  }
  if (height > 0 && width > 0) {
    cv::Mat cv_img_origin = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::resize(cv_img_origin, cv_img, cv::Size(height, width));
  } else {
    cv_img = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  }
  if (!cv_img.data) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Could not open or find file " << filename;
    return false;
  }
  datum->set_channels(3);
  datum->set_height(cv_img.rows);
  datum->set_width(cv_img.cols);
  datum->set_label(label);
  datum->clear_data();
  datum->clear_float_data();
  string* datum_string = datum->mutable_data();
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    for (int h = 0; h < cv_img.rows; ++h) {
      for (int w = 0; w < cv_img.cols; ++w) {
        datum_string->push_back(
            static_cast<char>(cv_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(h, w)[c]));
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And I have pasted the [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/iMS9Ab1F) on pastebin because it's 400 lines long.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If info not clear enough I can provide code

Comment: Show us the makefile; show us the code.

Comment: Could you compile it before you did the change ?

Comment: @DieterLücking you are a boss. now that is serious skill. edit: I am so bad at C++. let's go back to python

Comment: "The function still takes the same parameters and returns the same thing, so nothing to modify in the header file." - Not true, `const string&` and `string&` are not interchangeable.  So if they don't match, you're not defining the function declared in the header, and the missing symbol error is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the differences.

```
    1c1
    < bool ReadImageToDatum(const string& filename, const int label,
    ---
    > bool ReadImageToDatum(string& filename, const int label,
    3a4,8
    >   /* dalyac addition to read/follow symlink if symlink*/
    >   char buf[200];
    >   if (readlink(filename.c_str(), buf, 200) > 0) {
    >     filename = std::string(buf);
    >   }
```

I'd say that adding that const to the first argument is the culprit.

You should be able to get by with adding the const to the file declaration file and recompile...